# How to set Dialog box from stop opening default app in android?

Tags: android, pdf, dialog

what the problem i am facing is in android mobile when you have only one app for viewing PDF document, in that case when you select a pdf file it opens directly the existing app for viewing without asking any permission but when you have more than one app for viewing PDF file and when you select a file it will ask your permission to open which app for viewing. Well, what i need is it should ask permission even when i have only one app for viewing pdf file.
Can it be done in android device?

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote the PDF viewer app you could have it read the intent data for a file location on the phone to open the pdf file.

From the app that clicks the pdf file, you can start an intent and pass the file location with it after a pdf is clicked.